# Cast to Number failed for value "NaN" (type number) at path on a computed field Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In my schema I added 3 non required parameters `ratings` and `totalRating` which serve to auto calculate `averageRating`. When updating an existing record it all goes well, but singe the parameters record creation fails with `Product.create error: Error: Product validation failed: averageRating: Cast to Number failed for value "NaN" (type number) at path "averageRating"`.
I tried to add `ratings` and `totalRating` in the request body and setting their default to 0 but none helped. Still getting the error . Can you see why??

Schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    createdOnDate: { type: Number, required: true },
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    brand: { type: String, required: true },
    price: { type: Number, required: true },
    description: { type: String, required: true },
    category: { type: String, required: true },
    city: { type: String, required: true },
    region: { type: String, required: true },
    country: { type: String, required: true },
    vendor: { type: String, required: true },
    barcode: { type: String, required: true },
    imageUrl: { type: String, required: true },
    fullImages: { type: Array, required: true },
    thumbNails: { type: Array, required: true },
    // productImage: Uint8Array,
    minimumStock: { type: Number, required: true },
    availableQuantity: { type: Number, required: true },
    soldQuantity: { type: Number, required: true },
    totalRating: { type: Number, required: false, default: 0 },
    ratings: { type: Number, required: false, default: 0 },
    averageRating: {
        type: Number, required: false, default: function () {
            return (this.totalRating / this.ratings)
        }
    },

},
    { timestamps: true });

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema, 'Products');
```

sent json:

```
Mongoos createProduct req.body:  {
  name: 'someName',
  quantity: 5,
  price: 5.5,
  city: 'Bologna',
  region: 'Emilia-Romagna',
  country: 'Italy',
  category: 'bikes',
  vendor: 'zazza zenigata',
  createdOnDate: 132468754,
  availableQuantity: 5,
  soldQuantity: 0,
  minimumStock: 10,
  imageUrl: 'someUrl',
  barcode: 'someCode',
  description: 'someDescription',
  brand: 'someBrand',
  totalRating: 0,
  ratings: 0
}
```

error:

```
Product.create error: Error: Product validation failed: averageRating: Cast to Number failed for value "NaN" (type number) at path "averageRating"
    at ValidationError.inspect (/Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/validation.js:47:26)
    at formatValue (node:internal/util/inspect:757:19)
    at inspect (node:internal/util/inspect:336:10)
    at formatWithOptionsInternal (node:internal/util/inspect:1999:40)
    at formatWithOptions (node:internal/util/inspect:1881:10)
    at console.value (node:internal/console/constructor:327:14)
    at console.log (node:internal/console/constructor:363:61)
    at /Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/api/src/controllers/product.controller.js:79:17
    at /Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:16:11
    at /Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4892:21
    at _done (/Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3118:16)
    at /Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3133:18
    at callbackWrapper (/Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3087:20)
    at /Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4868:18
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:76:11) {
  errors: {
    averageRating: CastError: Cast to Number failed for value "NaN" (type number) at path "averageRating"
        at SchemaNumber.cast (/Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/number.js:373:11)
        at SchemaNumber.SchemaType.applySetters (/Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1106:12)
        at SchemaNumber.SchemaType.getDefault (/Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1052:25)
        at $__applyDefaults (/Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:437:24)
        at model.Document (/Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:165:5)
        at model.Model (/Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:105:12)
        at new model (/Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4706:15)
        at /Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3094:22
        at /Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3130:7
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at /Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3129:15
        at promiseOrCallback (/Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:9:12)
        at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (/Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:1149:10)
        at Function.create (/Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3064:23)
        at exports.createProduct (/Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/api/src/controllers/product.controller.js:42:11)
        at handleReturn (/Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/node_modules/express-promise-router/lib/express-promise-router.js:24:23) {
      stringValue: '"NaN"',
      messageFormat: undefined,
      kind: 'Number',
      value: NaN,
      path: 'averageRating',
      reason: AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: The expression evaluated to a falsy value:
      
        assert.ok(!isNaN(val))
      
          at castNumber (/Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/node_modules/mongoose/lib/cast/number.js:28:10)
          at SchemaNumber.cast (/Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/number.js:371:12)
          at SchemaNumber.SchemaType.applySetters (/Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1106:12)
          at SchemaNumber.SchemaType.getDefault (/Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1052:25)
          at $__applyDefaults (/Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:437:24)
          at model.Document (/Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:165:5)
          at model.Model (/Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:105:12)
          at new model (/Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4706:15)
          at /Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3094:22
          at /Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3130:7
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
          at /Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3129:15
          at promiseOrCallback (/Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:9:12)
          at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (/Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:1149:10)
          at Function.create (/Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3064:23)
          at exports.createProduct (/Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/api/src/controllers/product.controller.js:42:11) {
        generatedMessage: true,
        code: 'ERR_ASSERTION',
        actual: false,
        expected: true,
        operator: '=='
      },
      valueType: 'number'
    }
  },
  _message: 'Product validation failed'
}
Product.create: undefined
/Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:19
            throw error;
            ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:329:5)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:579:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (/Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:267:15)
    at ServerResponse.send (/Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:158:21)
    at /Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/api/src/controllers/product.controller.js:85:23
    at /Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:16:11
    at /Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4892:21
    at _done (/Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3118:16)
    at /Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3133:18
    at callbackWrapper (/Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3087:20)
    at /Volumes/ProjectsSSD/FixitServer/fixit_server_node/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4868:18
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:76:11) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}
```

Comment: It seems like the code is in working order! I think the "issue" is that your default values resolve to a NaN value i.e. 0/0 = NaN. And mongoose expects the type to be a Number, not a NaN value.

Comment: 0/0, why not keep the default 0,

Comment: Oh I see.  So maybe a default value of 1 would be the fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @amda pointed out using `virtual` I could make the `averageRating` to be calculated whenever updating the record.
His answer suggested a an array based approach, but I wanted to use the schema I already have not to refactor the update method I already had in place.

I tried using `.pre` to set the `averageRating` property as:

```
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    createdOnDate: { type: Number, required: true },
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    brand: { type: String, required: true },
    price: { type: Number, required: true },
    description: { type: String, required: true },
    category: { type: String, required: true },
    city: { type: String, required: true },
    region: { type: String, required: true },
    country: { type: String, required: true },
    vendor: { type: String, required: true },
    barcode: { type: String, required: true },
    imageUrl: { type: String, required: true },
    fullImages: { type: Array, required: true },
    thumbNails: { type: Array, required: true },
    // productImage: Uint8Array,
    minimumStock: { type: Number, required: true },
    availableQuantity: { type: Number, required: true },
    soldQuantity: { type: Number, required: true, default: 0 },

    totalRating: { type: Number, required: false, default: 0 },
    ratings: { type: Number, required: false, default: 0 },

    // using .pre => doesn't update averageRating
    averageRating: { type: Number, required: false, default: 0 },
},
    {
        timestamps: true
    });

productSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    // this.averageRating = this.totalRating > 0 ? this.totalRating / this.ratings : 0;
    this.averageRating = this.totalRating / this.ratings

    next();
});
```

but `averageRating` never updates..

Using `virtual` instead does work, I just had to add the returning toObject/toJson to include virtuals and now is working as I expected:

```
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    createdOnDate: { type: Number, required: true },
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    brand: { type: String, required: true },
    price: { type: Number, required: true },
    description: { type: String, required: true },
    category: { type: String, required: true },
    city: { type: String, required: true },
    region: { type: String, required: true },
    country: { type: String, required: true },
    vendor: { type: String, required: true },
    barcode: { type: String, required: true },
    imageUrl: { type: String, required: true },
    fullImages: { type: Array, required: true },
    thumbNails: { type: Array, required: true },
    // productImage: Uint8Array,
    minimumStock: { type: Number, required: true },
    availableQuantity: { type: Number, required: true },
    soldQuantity: { type: Number, required: true, default: 0 },

    totalRating: { type: Number, required: false, default: 0 },
    ratings: { type: Number, required: false, default: 0 },

    // using .pre doesn't update
    // averageRating: { type: Number, required: false, default: 0 },

},
    {
        timestamps: true,
        toObject: { virtuals: true },
        toJSON: { virtuals: true }
    });

productSchema.virtual("averageRating").get(function () {
    return this.totalRating > 0 ? this.totalRating / this.ratings : 0;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Both ratings and averageRating should be virtual fields: otherwise, the /0 division is going to crash your schema the moment you have an entry in your collection with `product.ratings = 0`. So what I would do is, firstly, define ratings by a getter function for a virtual field:

```
productSchema.virtual("numberRatings").get(function() {
    return this.ratings.length;
});
```

Assuming that `this.ratings` is a array where all the ratings for this particular product are stored. This way, each time you access `product.numerRatings`, the updated amount of entries in that array will be displayed.
With this in mind, you just need to add a little bit of conditional logic to your averageRating:

```
productSchema.virtual("averageRating").get(function() {
    return this.ratings.length > 0 ? this.totalRating / this.ratings.length : 0;
});
```

As long as there are no ratings in the array, `product.averageRating` will produce a 0, without attempting any problematic division. The moment that array starts containing ratings, an average will be computed.

Comment: I see, `ratings` is the number of ratings received, `totalRating` is the value to be diveded by `ratings` to calculate `averageRating`. So if I make the 3 parameters virtuals I should be fine mantaining them as `Number` right? If  change them to be `ratings` an array I will have to modify the `update` method.

Comment: I haven't accepted your answer only because it suggested an Array based approach instead of using what I have as a schema, but I upvoted it as it pointed me in the right direction. Many thanks

Comment: Happy to help. The main problem was de /0 division. The rest really depends on your needs

Comment: Indeed that was the problem. Many thanks again, still I wanna find out why using `averageRating` as real parameter and  `.pre` doesn't updated it.